# Animate a CGPath with a gradient fill

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, cabasicanimation, cgpath

I can create a bezier curve with gradient stroke (clear to red) using this code:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer (context, nil)
let path = createCurvePath()
path.stroke()
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .SourceIn)

let color1:CGColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor
let color2:CGColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor

let colors          = [color1, color2]
let colorSpace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let colorLocations :[CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.2]
let gradient        = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, colorLocations)
let startPoint      = CGPointMake(20, 20)
let endPoint        = CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height)

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsBeforeStartLocation)
CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context)
```

I now want to animate the stroke being drawn.
To animate the stroke, I add a `CAShapeLayer` and duplicate the path. I then add a `CABasicAnimation` to animate the path being stroked.

```
self.pathLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
self.pathLayer.path = path.CGPath

self.pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
self.pathLayer.fillColor = nil
self.pathLayer.lineWidth = 6.0
self.pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
self.pathLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

self.layer.addSublayer(self.pathLayer)

self.pathAnimation.duration = 1.5
self.pathAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
self.pathAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
self.pathAnimation.speed = 1

self.pathLayer.addAnimation(self.pathAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

As you can see, the pathLayer stroke colour is blue. My question is how do I apply the gradient to the path layer? I have tried using the same context approach as the non-animating line, but that has not worked for me; I get an invalid context error.